# build dev failed: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic2

When I try to serve the ionic app:

```
ionic serve
```

I get the error:

> build dev failed: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined

I am using ionic2, angular2, and firebase3.

Comment: Maybe check your code, search within to find indexOf and check to see if its trying to read an undefined variable

Comment: Please edit your post to include the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without seeing that, it will be hard to say anything more concrete than what the compiler already tells you.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using firebase @types? There seems to be a problem with that module

go to `node_modules/@types/firebase/index.d.ts`

and comment the line 326

```
export = Firebase;
```

That did it for me

Comment: This worked for me:  "Delete the firebase.d.ts in the folder node_modules\firebase."   https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/1713#issuecomment-267753479

Answer (score 1):

3 months ago, but After long time to search I found a solution.

If you're not using Firebase, this problem comes from ionic-app-script.
My project worked very well and after a `npm update` all my builds fail.

So to solve : update ionic-app-script from 0.47 to 0.48: after this there is still an error : `build dev failed: Cannot set property 'fileSystem' of null` .

So to solve again, update to 1.0.0.

PS : I had an other error with Lodash, to solve this, change your package to `"@types/lodash": "ts2.0"`

I hope it will help someone ... I could't say exactly why and where this error was throw (maybe `npm update` or `ionic lib update` but be careful with project updates.